# Ring homomorphism from matrix ring to smaller ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-rings

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be some finite field, and let $R := M_n(\mathbb{F})$ be the set of $n$-by-$n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}$. Then $R$ is finite. Does there exist some pair $(\varphi, S)$ such that $S$ is a ring with fewer elements than $R$ (but more than 1 element) and $\varphi : R \rightarrow S$ is a ring homomorphism?

The motivation for this question is practical rather than mathematical – the element $\varphi(A)$ would function like a MAC (message authentication code) for  $A$. Thus I would want it to have a smaller representation than $A$ (in terms of bits) but not so small that one could just "guess" it. A rng homomorphism would also be sufficient, i.e. the requirement $\varphi(1_R) = 1_S$ is not important, what matters is that $\varphi$ is homomorphic wrt both addition and multiplication.

But I assume the answer is negative either way, because if $R$ were a field, then $\varphi$ would have to be injective, and $R$ seems like it's "mostly" a field, having more invertible than non-invertible elements. However, I haven't managed to turn the idea into a proof. The trace is an additive map, the determinant is a multiplicative map, but netiher is both, and in fact $\mathbb{F}$ seems like it cannot be the target set at all, having no nilpotent elements except 0.

Comment: [This post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/126106/34894) indicates that the answer is no

Comment: I've found that post before asking – it's not clear to me why this answers the question. What if $S$ is not a matrix ring?

Comment: I use "indicate" to mean that the posts *suggests* that the answer will be no, not that it definitively gives an answer.  Intuitively though, I suspect that any suitable $S$ that has fewer elements than $R$ would be isomoprhic to a subring of $M_{n-1}(\Bbb F)$.

Comment: Ah, apologies. And yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to both questions is no.

First, there can be no (unit-preserving) ring homomorphism from $R = M_{n}(\Bbb F)$ to a smaller ring $S$.  We note that for any ring-hom $\varphi:R \to S$, $\ker\varphi$ must form a two-sided ideal in $R$.  However, $R = M_{n}(\Bbb F)$ is a simple ring: its only two-sided ideals are $R$ and $\{0\}$.  Thus, the image of $\varphi$ must be isomorphic either to $R/\{0\} \cong R$, or to $R/R \cong \{0\}$.

This also rules out the possibility of a rng-homomorphism. Note that we can always restrict the codomain so that $\varphi:R \to S$ is surjective.  We note that for any $s \in S$, there exists an $r \in R$ with $\varphi(r) = s$ and we have
$$
\varphi(1_R) \, s = \varphi(1_R) \varphi(r) = \varphi(r) = s\\
s\,\varphi(1_R) = \varphi(r)\varphi(1_R) = \varphi(r) = s.
$$
That is, $S$ must have identity element $\varphi(1)$, which is to say that any onto rng-homomorphism from $R$ to $S$ is necessarily identity-preserving.

Comment: Thank you very much! In that case, the MAC will just have to be as large as the original matrix after all.

Comment: I don't understand why your MAC would have to be both additive and multiplicative, seems a bit stronger than it needs to be

Comment: I might not actually be allowed to describe what the problem is in more detail, but multiplicativity and additivity are definitely essential. It's not a MAC in the technical sense, just something that's always called a MAC since it does more or less the same thing.